# USB communication via ethernet

Tags: connection, usb, connection-string, ethernet, usbserial

I'm trying to figure out how I could emulate a USB port from one computer to another over the internet.

I want to connect a device in one city with software running on a computer in another city. Normally this is done with a regular usb cable so I have to go there and plug in, but I wish I could connect to this device remotely.

My idea was for the person who is in the place of the device to connect his computer to the device and then we would connect his usb port to my computer via the internet, in such a way that the internet connection between the two computers would work exactly like a usb cable. Unfortunately, solutions such as remote desktop or teamviewer do not work because the device support program cannot be installed on a computer other than mine.

The second idea was to program two microcontrollers that would communicate with each other via the Internet and one would be connected to my computer and the other to the device.

Do you think it would be possible to do something like this, if so, which idea is better?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible. Just search for "USB over IP" or "USB redirector". In on of my previous jobs we used some USB over IP hubs for access to USB license keys from multiple sites.
Of course this might not work in case your device is sensitive to latency or requires very high throughput.

BTW there are even USB over UTP things, but those are just pairs of devices allowing connection of USB device using few dozens meters standard UTP CAT6 cable but can not communicate over network.